# Find two closest numbers to zero in given array in Java Script

Tags: javascript

Is there any better solution than these(Solution 1 and Solution 2 )? Can you please suggest.

**Solution 1:**

```js
var arr = [2, 5.5, -3, 10, -1, 1.5];


let min1 = arr[0],
  min2 = arr[1];

for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (Math.abs(arr[i]) < Math.abs(min1)) {
    min1 = arr[i];

  }
  if (Math.abs(min2) > Math.abs(min1)) {
    let temp = min2;
    min2 = min1;
    min1 = temp;
  }
}

console.log("Closest numbers to Zero = " + min1 + ", " + min2);
```

**Solution 2:**

```js
var arr = [2, 5.5, -3, 10, -1, 1.5];
arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b));
console.log("Closest numbers to Zero = " + arr[0] + ", " + arr[1]);
```

Comment: You can use a min heap. With a little bit of tweaking you will get the result in O(1) which is better than O(nlogn) of the sorting method

Comment: Define "better". I'd think the `sort` approach is perfectly fine for everyday use. It's concise and accurate. In what dimension do you want to improve it?

Comment: You could also use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the variables (though it doesn't necessarily make the code 'better'), for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/0591wqcj/

Comment: I would prefer the first one as you're not gonna use sorted array for any later use case, all you need is two numbers which are close to zero, so you should just loop through array and two minimum numbers, as you're doing in first one

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

```
var arr = [2, 5.5, -3, 10, -1, 1.5];
arr.push(0);
arr.sort();// [-1, -3, 0, 1.5, 10, 2, 5.5]
num1 = arr[arr.indexOf(0)-1];//-3
num2 = arr[arr.indexOf(0)+1];//1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest to zero just means the lowest absolute value, so you just need to calculate that and then find the two smallest results.

```js
let arr = [2, 5.5, -3, 10, -1, 1.5];
let abs = arr.map(x=>Math.abs(x));
for(let t=0;t<2;t++)
 {
 let lowestI = 0;
 for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++)
 {
   if (abs[i] < abs[lowestI]) {lowestI = i;}
 }
 console.log((t+1)+".-closest number to zero:",arr[lowestI]);
 arr.splice(lowestI,1)
 abs.splice(lowestI,1)
}
```

The complexity is `n*t`, so this would only be useful if t is very low (like the 2 in your case) and the length is very high, else the sorting approach with n*log(n) would be more than sufficient.